# Forgotten the pin code to my Pixel 6( non pro version) - remove pin code without data loss

Tags: google-pixel-6

I changed my pin code of my phone but I have forgotten what the code is. I can't do a factory reset because the phone is used as a two factor authtentication for my password vault. I stupidly didnt setup a backup code for the password vault.

Is there a way I can remove/reset the pin code?

I hear that adb can do it but I don't think I enabled usb debugging. I hear you can reset it via google androd device manager but I can't login to my google account because the password is in the valut and has 2FA and again i didn't setup a backup code.

Comment: https://github.com/urbanadventurer/Android-PIN-Bruteforce

Comment: The PIN code is a security measure. Only the person knowing the PIN code is allowed to use the phone and access the data. If you could bypass it then the PIN code would be of no use as everybody could break it.

Comment: @SmartManoj Brute forcing the PIN should not be possible as each wrong PIN increases the waiting time. After a few wrong PINs entered the waiting time should go up to multiple hours or even a day so it can take years to just test all 4 digit PINs.

Comment: I have found a way to reset the timer. It's incredibly simple. My 6 year old nephew could do it.  I'm not posting it here because I suspect all android phones have this issue.